# RIP Verne Troyer, star of Austin Powers

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Verne Troyer, best known for playing Mini-Me in the Austin Powers movies, has died at the age of 49. In addition to his iconic role, he also portrayed the original Griphook in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

[image]

Comment: `ofttimes a very small man can cast a very large shadow.` -[GRRM](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/382057-a-shadow-on-the-wall-varys-murmured-yet-shadows-can)

Comment: That's very sad :'(